# How do I change the origin of a css animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

With transforms you can change the origin, but there doesnt appear to be a animation-origin property. Does anyone know how to change the origin of an animation.
for example I have a css grow animation, where a red square grows into existence on the screen, but it grows from the left upper corner, I would like to grow it from the middle

https://jsfiddle.net/b9cezvoz/26/

```
@keyframes myFrames{
  0%{
      width: 0px;
      height: 0px;
  }
  100%{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red
  }
}

div{
  animation: myFrames .2s ease-in-out 0s 5 alternate both;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the transform-origin is the key but to you if you use transform scale and scale to 100%. 
However if you use scale AND set an initial width/height of 0, the animation won't work (because 0x100 is 0) so ensure you don't set initial 0 values on the width/height properties when scaling. 
You could set to 1px and scale to 100% from there (and optionally set visibility to hidden and then visible at 100 - but that could have variable results, you may need more keyframes)

Advisable is that you give the div in question an id or class name and assign the css values to just that id as opposed to `div` in general, as this will affect all your divs.

```css
@keyframes myFrames {
  0% {
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

#redsquare {
  margin: 100px auto 0px auto;
  animation: myFrames .2s ease-in-out 0s 5 alternate both;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: scale(100, 100);
}
```

```html
<div id="redsquare">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do so by using the transform scale property

```
@keyframes myFrames{
      0%{

         transform:scale(0)
      }
      100%{
        background-color: red;
         transform:scale(1)
      }
    }

div{width: 100px;height: 100px; animation: myFrames 1s ease-in-out 0s 5 alternate both; transform-origin:center center;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b9cezvoz/27/